# iOS 14: How to delay the "[App Name] would like to find and connect to devices on your local network" notification?

Tags: ios, xcode

I watched the wwdc video at:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10110/
and at 9:30 of the video, it showed me an improved sample app where the notification doesn't immediately display, until the user triggered the feature later. However, the video didn't explain what changes were made to delay the notification.
Sample app by wwdc is downloadable here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/building_a_custom_peer-to-peer_protocol

Meanwhile, my current app does not access Bonjour services until later in the app, but the notification triggers upon launch.
Does anyone know how to delay it, like the sample app does?

Comment: You might not be accessing Bonjour but you are accessing the local network.

Comment: Thanks, yeah after some commenting out, it turns out the notification does not always run upon launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks matt for pointing out that there are other ways to access the local network.

In my case, the app was accessing Chromecast upon launch, triggering the notification.